# Overleaf citation multiply defined with A&A class file

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, labels, overleaf, warnings

In Overleaf, when citing a reference within the document class `aa` from the [A&A Latex package](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa-package.zip) (from the journal Astronomy and Astrophysics) and compiling with TexLive2021, I get a warning `Package natbib Warning: Citation 'knuth-acp' multiply defined`. However, the bib file only contains one entry, so the label should not be defined multiply.

The warning does not appear with the document class `article` and/or compiling with TexLive2020. However, I need TexLive2021 and the document class `aa` for another project (TexLive2021 because I require a new version of the `siunitx` package, which is not present in TexLive2020).

I know I can ignore the warning, but in principle this can disguise warnings about labels that are actually defined multiply.

What is the reason for the warnings and how can I fix them?

The minimal working examples (MWEs) are:

---

**MWE (Overleaf):** https://www.overleaf.com/read/kqkzzqphzqyv

---

**MWE (direct):**

main.tex (tex file):

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[letter]{aa}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth-acp}

\bibliographystyle{aa}
\bibliography{lit_test}

\end{document}
```

lit_test.bib (bib file):

```
@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
```

aa.bst: [A&A Latex package](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa-package.zip) (file too long to paste)

aa.cls: [A&A Latex package](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa-package.zip) (file too long to paste)

Comment: `aaa.cls` messes with `\enddocument` in a way that is probably not compatible with modern LaTeX kernels. I can see that this version of `aa.cls` is from 2016. Aren't there any newer versions?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think. A&A updated at least the documentation of the package in October 2020, but it seems there is no update to the `aa.cls` file from 2016.

Comment: See also https://www.aanda.org/for-authors.

Comment: having the same issue and would like to use TexLive2022.

Answer (score 2):

As the OP pointed out, switching to `TexLive2020` in the overleaf configuration is a quick workaround, for those who do not need `TexLive2021`. Thx.