# Longtable not generated, but no compilation errors

Tags: longtable

**Issues:** When compiling a minimal example (see below) using the document class `aa.cls` (from the journal Astronomy & Astrophysics) with [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/project) under TexLive2021, the `longtable` (table over multiple pages) is not generated. Unfortunately, no compilation error is generated, which makes it more difficult to track the issue. A second, less important, issue occurs, where a warning about citations being multiply defined is displayed, despite not having any duplicate bib entries (see [Overleaf citation multiply defined with A&A class file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625901/113493)).

**Context:** Both issues do not occur when:

- compiling with TexLive2020
- using the `article.cls` document class and compiling with TexLive2020 or TexLive2021

Both issues are thus related to the `aa.cls` class file, which can be downloaded from the [A&A Latex package](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa-package.zip). Unfortunately the latest version of this class file available is still from September 2016.

Using `\listfiles` I have already checked which packages are loaded when compiling under TexLive2020 and TexLive2021 and which ones of them have different package versions (using diff). I replaced the corresponding files (of types `.cls, .sty, .clo, .def`) in Overleaf with those of the latest (as of 2022-01-18) package versions available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/) by uploading renamed files and loading those. Except for the `babel` package and `l3backend-pdftex.def` (from the `l3backend` package) I managed to manually replace all files and compilation with TexLive2020 still worked. My naive guess therefore is that the issue is located within `l3backend-pdftex.def` (`l3backend-pdfmode.def`) or somewhere else in the compiler. I also downloaded the entire directory and compiled under the TexLive2019 distribution (with older package versions), which is installed at my workplace. No issues, no compilation errors. I do not have the rights to update the workplace distribution, so I cannot do further local checking, unfortunately.

**Questions: What exactly could cause the longtable issue (and less importantly the citation one)? Can it be fixed easily (maybe just by updating `aa.cls`) and if so, how?**

---

**Minimal example:**

main.tex (tex file):

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{aa}

\listfiles

%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth-acp}

\longtab{
\begin{longtable}{lllrrr}
\caption{\label{kstars} Sample stars with absolute magnitude}\\
\hline\hline
Catalogue& $M_{V}$ & Spectral & Distance & Mode & Count Rate \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{continued.}\\
\hline\hline
Catalogue& $M_{V}$ & Spectral & Distance & Mode & Count Rate \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
%%
Gl 33    & 6.37 & K2 V & 7.46 & S & 0.043170\\
Gl 66AB  & 6.26 & K2 V & 8.15 & S & 0.260478\\
Gl 68    & 5.87 & K1 V & 7.47 & P & 0.026610\\
         &      &      &      & H & 0.008686\\
Gl 86
\footnote{Source not included in the HRI catalog. See Sect.~5.4.2 for details.}
         & 5.92 & K0 V & 10.91& S & 0.058230\\
\end{longtable}
}

\bibliographystyle{aa}
\bibliography{lit_test}

\end{document}
```

lit_test.bib (bib file):

```
@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
```

aa.bst (bib style file): [A&A Latex package](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa-package.zip) (too long too paste)

aa.cls (class file): [A&A Latex package](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa-package.zip) (too long too paste)

---

Different package versions when compiling under TexLive2020 and TexLive2021:

```
>  article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
<  article.cls    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
>   size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
<   size10.clo    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
> inputenc.sty    2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
< inputenc.sty    2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
> fancyhdr.sty    2019/01/31 v3.10 Extensive control of page headers and footers
< fancyhdr.sty    2021/01/28 v4.0.1 Extensive control of page headers and footers
>  amsmath.sty    2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
<  amsmath.sty    2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
> longtable.sty    2020/01/07 v4.13 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
< longtable.sty    2021-05-07 v4.16 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
>    babel.sty    2020/07/13 3.47 The Babel package
<    babel.sty    2021/07/22 3.63 The Babel package
> graphicx.sty    2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
< graphicx.sty    2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
> graphics.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
< graphics.sty    2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>   pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
<   pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
>   ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
<   ifthen.sty    2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
> l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-06-29 L3 backend support: PDF mode
< l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-07-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
```

Comment: The class redefines `\enddocument` and so basically breaks `\AtEndDocument` in a current LaTeX. The longtable reappears if one reinstate the original `\enddocument` with `\let\orienddocument\enddocument \documentclass{aa} \let\enddocument\orienddocument` but I didn't check why they did the redefinition and so if this breaks something else. You should report this to the class maintainer.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll write to A&A and will report the issue.

Comment: Seems replacing the `\documentclass{aa}` with your code will cause a `LastPage` (number of all pages) reference to be undefined. But let's see what A&A says.

Comment: yes, adding this label seems to be the only purpose of the redefinition. Try the lastpage package.

Comment: Did anyone ever find the solution for this? I am using the last A&A package on overleaf in 2023 and I am still encountering the same issue!

Comment: @JuliaRoquette: OP here. I just checked my overleaf containing the demo article. As mentioned in my comment from Jan 18, 2022, the fix provided by Ulrike Fischer in the comments causes the last page reference to be undefined. However, I had contacted A&A via mail, and their production office had sent me a zip archive containing a modified *aa.cls* file that solves both issues (I also retested this using TexLive 2023, 2022 and 2021 (legacy)). Why A&A did not update their A&A Latex package afterwards, I do not know.

Comment: Hi @bproxauf, thanks a lot for your feedback! I have also contacted them last week as well, but no news so far.

Comment: @JuliaRoquette: If you want, I can share the modified *aa.cls* with you (e.g. via Google Drive). I'll double-check, but as far as I remember, it did not contain any specific info applicable only to me. You can try that class file and see whether the issues are fixed. Let me know.

Comment: That would be lovely @bproxauf! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JuliaRoquette: You can download the modified class file from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S_zJStOUM80JFXwcDUhJnFNJtniGs4ZN/view?usp=sharing. Let me know when you have downloaded the file and whether it works. I suggest to stay in contact with A&A in any case, as this should be fixed in the official A&A package.