# Package natbib Warning: Citation `)' multiply defined

Tags: bibtex, natbib, acm, acmart

When building a paper I'm writing for an ACM conference, I am getting the following error using the **latest** acmart files:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `)' multiply defined.
```

Further, I receive this error alongside the following:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `ufactory' on page 3 undefined on input line 21.
```

The above citation undefined message only appears for 3 misc citations as seen below, and the first warning message disappears when I remove the 3 misc citations.

In the `output.aux` file, I see the following for these citations:

`\bibcite{)}{{33}{[n.\,d.(@}{{SDRplay}}{{}}}`

`\bibcite{)}{{37}{[n.\,d.(@}{{uArm Developer}}{{}}}`

`\bibcite{)}{{38}{[n.\,d.(@}{{UFACTORY}}{{}}}`

The packages I am using in the preamble are as follows:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,anonymous,table]{acmart}

% Packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

**Citations**:

```
@misc{sdrplay2022, title={SDRuno}, url={https://www.sdrplay.com/sdruno}, author={SDRplay}}
@misc{ufactory, title={UFactory UArm}, url={https://www.ufactory.cc/uarm}, author={UFACTORY}}
@misc{uarmdeveloper, title={UARM-developer/UARM-Python-SDK: New Python Library for Swift, swift pro}, url={https://github.com/uArm-Developer/uArm-Python-SDK/tree/2.0}, author={uArm-Developer}}
```

---

**EDIT:**

The latest acmart files can be gathered on the official site: https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

The latex document MWE can be seen here:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,anonymous,table]{acmart} % anonymous

% Packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% \graphicspath{{img/}}


\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{$#1 _ #2$}
\newcommand{\paragraphb}[1]{\vspace{0.03in}\noindent{\bf #1} }

\begin{document}

\title{My Paper}

\author{James Smith, John Nash}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{My Afill}
    \city{City}
    \country{ABC}
}
\email{{first.last}@afill.com}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}


\keywords{a, b, c}
\maketitle

I used
uFactory's uARM Swift Pro~\cite{ufactory} and ... using
the uARM Python (3.8.X) SDK~\cite{uarmdeveloper}. The data capture ... uses ..
SDRuno~\cite{sdrplay2022} with ...

% References
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

And the `references.bib` file used is simply the following, omitting all other references used:

```
@misc{sdrplay2022, title={SDRuno}, url={https://www.sdrplay.com/sdruno}, author={SDRplay}}
@misc{ufactory, title={UFactory UArm}, url={https://www.ufactory.cc/uarm}, author={UFACTORY}}
@misc{uarmdeveloper, title={UARM-developer/UARM-Python-SDK: New Python Library for Swift, swift pro}, url={https://github.com/uArm-Developer/uArm-Python-SDK/tree/2.0}, author={uArm-Developer}}
```

Comment: Please extend your example into a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. The example should of course show the problem you report. As your question sits here we have no idea what you did in your document.

Comment: @daleif thanks for the suggestion. here's a MWE people can use to test.

Comment: Erh, none of the articles you cite are listed in the bibdata you provided. you need to use `sdrplay2022`, `ufactory` etc

Comment: @daleif my bad! I renamed them in an attempt to fix, I've updated the OP

Comment: @rshah  I run `pdflatex`->`bibtex`->`pdflatex`->`pdflatex`. In the last `pdflatex`, I only got `Class acmart Warning: Do not put several authors in the same \author macro! on 
input line 23.`. It is run on TeX Live 2022.

Comment: I get the same as Clara no citation issues. Additionally the 90s called, `\bf` has been depreciated  since 1993. Use `\textbf{...}`.

Comment: Well this is really strange, as I am getting these errors when trying to build. It is only with these three citations as well. I will take note of `\bf` to `\textbf` :)

Comment: Did you try the small `.bib` file with only the three entries, or your original file with all the entries? Maybe in your original file there is an error in an earlier entry, which causes the `)` problem and also leads to the remaining entries being skipped and therefore undefined.

Comment: @Marijn yes I did. It looks like the issue was caused by the latest ACM files so reverting back seem to have fixed the issue!

Comment: for A&A papers see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625901/overleaf-citation-multiply-defined-with-aa-class-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce the bug with the current ACM bibliography style downloaded from the link provided in the question (https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). This is version 2.1 of ACM-Reference-Format.bst which was written for acmart.cls version 1.79, dated 14 June 2017. The current version of acmart.cls is newer (2022/04/09 v1.84) but recent changes focus on BibLaTeX support with the BibTeX style remaining unchanged.

The class supports both numeric and author-year citations (for BibTeX as well as BibLaTeX). Numeric is default, but the `.bst` file generates the author-year labels in both cases in the optional argument of the `\bibitem` entries in the `.bbl` file (which are ignored with the numeric style).

For entries without a `year` field this creates a problem. The label formatter contains the following code:

```
year empty.or.unknown
    { "[n.\,d.]" }
    { year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$}
```

This generates entries in the `.bbl` file such as the following:

```
\bibitem[SDRplay([n.\,d.])]%
        {sdrplay2022}
```

Because `[]` around `n.\,d.` is not escaped, the optional argument is parsed incorrectly and the `)` after the first `]` is parsed as the citekey for each entry without a year.

You can fix this bug by editing ACM-Reference-Format.bst, specifically `FUNCTION { calc.basic.label }` and `FUNCTION { calc.label }`. Removing the brackets from `n.\,d.` in both functions is sufficient:

```
year empty.or.unknown
    { "n.\,d." }
    { year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$}
```

Then the (unused) optional argument looks like this:

```
\bibitem[SDRplay(n.\,d.)]%
        {sdrplay2022}
```

And the document compiles correctly:

[image]

Note that the bibliography still shows `[n.d.]` with square brackets, this output is from a different function in the `.bst` file that is unrelated to the formatting of the optional citekey.

Comment: Note that the (official) Github version at https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart already has a fix for this bug (slightly different from the one I propose here but a similar idea), this just hasn't been propagated to the ACM website yet.