# Package natbib Warning in Astronomy and Astrophysics overleaf template

Tags: natbib, overleaf

I am writing a paper in the Astronomy and Astrophysics overleaf template. However, I am getting multiple warning messages like: Package natbib Warning: Citation `2013MNRAS.436..774E' multiply defined.

I have not mentioned the citations in multiple places, but I am confused as to why this is showing.

Comment: Note that you should always provide a code example. Then we know exactly wjat yu are doing.

Comment: It's complaining that your bib file has multiple entries with the same key `2013MNRAS.436..774E`

Comment: @DaiBowen My guess as well, but I do not get a natbib warning if I have a duplicate entry in the bib file when I test. I though it might be an overleaf thing but not I cannot recreate such a warning.

Comment: @daleif hmm, was (apparently overconfident) assumption, [looks like `aa` may just be incompatible with newer kernels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625901/106162)

Comment: @DaiBowen if I switch my simple exmaple to the `aa` class, then it fails. I can get the OPs warning if I use TL2021 and ignore the warning from bibtex. In any case I think your assesment is correct.